# Kubernetes jobs getting failed with ephemeral-storage issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

So far our on-prem kubernetes cluster is working fine. Lately we are seeing jobs are  failing with the below error. I checked there are no space issues on Kube master as well as the worker nodes. There is plenty of space available under "/var/lib" as well as under persistent volume claims.

```
Version:

Client Version: v1.17.2
Server Version: v1.17.2

Host OS:
Centos 7.7

CNI:
Weave
```

Error:

> The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage.Container main was
>   using 5056Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container wait was using
>   12Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.

any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks,
CS

Comment: I believe you are using docker as the CRI for containers. Can you paste the output of `docker info` command, I need to check the storage driver and `fs` sizes.

Comment: Are you using `EmptyDir`? Because pod that uses that volume without storage quotas will fill it up. If you generating a lot of log files you can also try to limit [logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) and it's `max size.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why this could be happening is that pod logs, or `emptyDir` usage are filling up your ephemeral storage.

> Docker takes a conservative approach to cleaning up unused objects (often referred to as “garbage collection”), such as images, containers, volumes, and networks: these objects are generally not removed unless you explicitly ask Docker to do so. This can cause Docker to use extra disk space.

You can use docker function called `prune`. This will clean up the system from unused objects. If you wish to cleanup multiple objects you can use `docker system prune`. Check here more about [prunning](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/).

There is also another tool called `Garbage collector`. It`s docker tool that removes.  unused/abandoned/orphaned blobs. Check here [more](https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/) about it.

> In the context of the Docker registry, garbage collection is the process of removing blobs from the filesystem when they are no longer referenced by a manifest. Blobs can include both layers and manifests.

If this does`t help you can try to [configure logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) and set its limit:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3",
    "labels": "production_status",
    "env": "os,customer"
  }
}
```

There is also another option if `emptyDir` has been used. Using `emptyDir` you allow 
container to write any amount of storage to it's node fs.  You can [request or limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#requests-and-limits-setting-for-local-ephemeral-storage) settings for local ephemeral storage by setting up:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: test-image
    resources:
      requests:
        ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
      limits:
        ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
  - name: test
    image: test-image2
    resources:
      requests:
        ephemeral-storage: "2Gi"
      limits:
        ephemeral-storage: "2Gi"
```

You can also check the containers running using `docker ps` and then inspect the container by yourself and locate the fs.

It should be found at this location:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id>-json.log
```

Let me know if that helps.